# fullPage.js in Joomla template Gantry

Tags: joomla, fullpage.js

How can I implement http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ in joomla template (Gantry 5). 
I tried to add scripts in "Page settings" Aton custom javascript, add module with

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

but nothing happened. Maybe someone already tried.

Comment: You can check [the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)?

Answer (score 0):

I like the Inspire Theme particle for one page nav: http://demo.inspiretheme.com/particles/index.php/particles/onepage-nav

You could use that for all the javascript, etc and if you wanted it to work in a traditional Joomla menu, you could just set the items up as external links with the IDs to each section like #g-mainbottom or whatnot.